# JPA's EntityManager or Hibernate's HibernateTemplate with Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have decided to use Spring, Hibernate, and Restlet to create a web service. I am new to all of these three technologies. My question is this: How do I decide whether to use JPA's `EntityManager` or Hibernate's `HibernateTemplate`?

Code snippet for JPA's EntityManager:

```
protected EntityManager entityManager;

@PersistenceContext
public void setEngityManager(EntityManager entityManger) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}
```

Code snippet for Hibernate's HibernateTemplate:

```
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

@Autowired
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    this.hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are someone who like `interface-based-implementation`, then JPA is the interface definition and Hibernate is one of the implementations. We decided to use JPA semantics in our project (with a very long term plan to replace Hibernate with something similar and light-weight probably).

Comment: But I have heard that the Hibernate API provides some functionalities that JPA does not. Also do you use JPQL instead of HQL?(There seems to be greater support for HQL in the open-source community) Or do you just use SQL?

Comment: We use JPQL instead of HQL and it has addresses all our use cases so far. If you need any specific feature of Hibernate that has no counterpart in the JPA specification, you could take that as an exception, get the SessionFactory using entityManager.getDelegate, but I doubt if such a specific requirement will not have a workaround with JPA semantics itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to `hibernate` in future, then no point in using `EntityManagerFactory`, you can go ahead and use `SessionFactory`. And just inject definition for this using java based configuration or xml. It must be available in `application context`. 
But in future if you might want to move to different jpa provider, like toplink etc, then you should use EntityManagerFactory as it allows you to have implementation from various provider. Because providers implement jpa specification. So in future you just need to have different configuration in your application context and you should be able to use that.